# LED strip calculate power

Tags: transistors, led-strip

I bought a few LED strips. 
I have a power supply with 12V and 15W, the strip is blinking. So I assume - not enough power!?

[image]

I have 5m strip, what power supply do I need for this? And for 10 or 15m?

Comment: If you provide more details (like where you bought it, perhaps an exact link to the source) this would probably lead to more precise results. There's very different types of LEDs out there ranging from a few mW to a few W (rare, but possible).

Comment: The specification should tell you the required power, typically in watts/metre (W/m).

Comment: From memory, people usually seem to reckon on about 1A per metre of LED strip - so you're way short.

Comment: LED's very greatly in power consumption (current), so without specific details we would be guessing, and that is not our job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work a bit with LED strips and here's how I conceptualize them.

The "stock, basic" LED strip is 5 metres long (16') and has 300 LEDs (single density).  That's 60 per metre.  They make double density (600 LEDs/strip, 120/metre) and many other variations, but most start from this baseline.

Strips with 3528** devices are 1 channel, i.e. monochrome.  Strips with 5050 devices are 3 channels (note each "LED" has 3 emitters and 6 pins), typically Red Green Blue, but White White White is also common.

Rule of thumb for power planning is **2 amps per channel for 300 LEDs** (basic strip).   So

- a basic 300-LED 3528 roll will be 2 amps.
- a basic 300-LED 5050 roll will be 6 amps (3 channels remember).
- a double-density 600-LED roll of 3528s will be 4 amps.

---

From your photo, it looks like you have 5050 emitters in normal density (300 per 5 metres).  As discussed above, you can expect a 5 metre run of these to draw 6 amps, or 1.2 amps per metre.

If you want watts, multiply by your supply voltage (12).

*Note they only have 2 solder pads at each cut point, so the LED strip is made to be monochrome, even though it's using 5050 devices.  (Many monochrome 5050 LED strips use RGB strip material, which has 3 channels and 4 solder points, allowing you to control each 1/3 of the LED separately.  Not this one.  Even though it only has 2 solder pads, it draws current like 3 channels, since it is 5050.) 5050s are used for triple the light output of 3528s.*

15 metres of these things, I would plan for 18A / 216W of supply power.

You know, this will be a *lot* of light.

---

** 3528 and 5050 come from the package dimensions, 3.5mm x 2.8mm and 5mm square.